# How to connect to hdfs deployed in the docker?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I deployed hadoop and spark from this project https://github.com/Marcel-Jan/docker-hadoop-spark 
I've completed instructions "Quick Start Spark (PySpark)" in readme and got a dataframe from hdfs

I need to do the same thing but through airflow. I successfull connect to spark master:

```
spark = (SparkSession
        .builder
        # .master('local')
        .master("spark://127.0.0.1:7077")
        .appName("Test")
        .getOrCreate())
```

But when i tried to reach hadoop cluster, i got the error

```
 Call From SPB-379/127.0.1.1 to namenode:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

I understand that airflow doesn't see address "namenode" and i tried to execute command -
`docker inspect <hadoop container id>` and get

```
 "Networks": {
            "docker-hadoop-spark_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "namenode",
                    "namenode",
                    "8a06dd5cca57"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "f57164de9f26ef3a1a33c4ee46b24903c0824009ecfeda06f7f45ba9206f6a0a",
                "EndpointID": "6bf662634c9ef925dc435d8a28364b045ef8b572e22f5c5316257ada2a52cc0d",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.19.0.9",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:09",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
```

But this ipaddress also gave a error. I am not confident that this way is correct and i want to give any feedback:)

For a better understanding
It works
[image]
It doesn't work
[image]
Network config of the docker-compose
[image]

Error - allocate worker to airflow

```
22/12/26 19:54:02 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.deploy.DeployMessages$ExecutorUpdated; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1654279024112373855, local class serialVersionUID = -1971851081955655249
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says `namenode:9000` could not be resolved from your host. Regarding airflow, you need to ensure it is also running as a container, and not on your host, then Spark code will execute within the Docker network as well.

I have a Docker example [here](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/hdfs-reader.ipynb) that works fine from a Spark notebook.

Comment: port 9870 use for hadoop web ui? but airflow actually works in my host, i'll try to deploy it in a docker and come back...

Comment: in your project you connect to local master. When i connect to local master project also work, but in a cluster as a spark://<ip>:7077 it doesn't work

Comment: Airflow and Spark need to connect to the namenode RPC port, not the web UI. For Unknown host errors like you're getting, then your host (or Airflow installed on your host, running Spark jobs) will be unable to resolve Docker container hostnames such as `namenode`. That's what the error is saying

Comment: yeah i understood but when i wrote an ip address of namenode, i also get an error. Spark in the same container with hadoop and when i connected to spark through terminal, hdfs:namenode:9000 worked, but through airflow didn't work

Comment: i have added screenshots in question body to you

Comment: Error is saying the underscore is not a valid character. Make sure you don't set that FQDN listed in the error anywhere in your Spark/Hadoop config files. By the way, the namenode will also return the network addresses (hostnames) of the datanodes to determine block locations. You should never use IP addresses to connect to services in a Docker bridge network. Also, you don't need to put `hdfs://host:port` in Spark code. It should already have `fs.defaultFs` property set via the Compose file

Comment: `docker-hadoop-spark_default` is the name of my docker-compose (i added screenshot of network inspect). This network contains subnets of containers for each application (hadoop, spark, etc.), the name node address is 172.19.0.5 (the one I'm trying to pass to airflow). So when I pass this address it converts it to `namenode.docker-hadoop-spark_default`

Comment: but I still don't understand which address to insert into the airflow code to connect to hdfs
You said I don't need to insert `<ip>:<host>` directly (172.19.0.5:7077 for example). But also airflow don't understand aliases like `namenode` or `docker-hadoop-spark_default`.
So what should I do to make my airflow see hdfs?

Comment: 1) Your inspect command doesn't show anything related to airflow. Like I said, never use IP addresses 2) You can provide a custom network name that doesn't have an underscore 3) Airflow is running Spark; Airflow doesn't really need to connect to HDFS itself. For Spark, you only need `read().json("/bill...")` since it already is setup with a default filesystem.

Comment: i placed airflow in docker-compose with hadoop and spark, now airflow see addresses but spark master doesn't allocate worker to read dataframe from hdfs. I added error in question

Comment: InvalidClassException is related to some Java version rather than networking, Docker, Spark, or Airflow. I'm not sure, but ensure you're running Java 11 at most everywhere