How to set up a connection between Spark code and Spark container using Docker?
I am working with a Docker setup for Hadoop and Spark using the following repository: docker-hadoop-spark. My Docker Compose YAML configuration is working correctly, and I am able to run the containers without issues.
Here is the YAML configuration:
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9010:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
      CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS: hdfs://namenode:9000
    ports:
      - "9864:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:3.0.0-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-master
    depends_on:
      - namenode
      - datanode
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000

  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:3.0.0-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000

  hive-server:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-server
    depends_on:
      - namenode
      - datanode
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL: "jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "hive-metastore:9083"
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"

  hive-metastore:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-metastore
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    command: /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode:9864 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432"
    ports:
      - "9083:9083"

  hive-metastore-postgresql:
    image: bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0
    container_name: hive-metastore-postgresql

  presto-coordinator:
    image: shawnzhu/prestodb:0.181
    container_name: presto-coordinator
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"

volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:

However, I'm having trouble connecting my Spark code to the Spark container. Specifically, even though I have configured my Spark code to connect via port 9010, it seems to default to port 9000 instead. here is my Spark code with errors written inside the code as comment:
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object HiveCheck {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("HiveMetastoreCheck")
      .master("spark://spark-master:7077")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://namenode:9010")
      .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hive-metastore:9083")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

      println("Databases in Hive:")
      spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show()

    // Works fine. Output:
    //    +---------+
    //    |namespace|
    //    +---------+
    //    |  default|
    //    +---------+

      println("Tables in database 'default':")
      spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN default").show()

    // Works fine. Output:
    //    +--------+----------+-----------+
    //    |database| tableName|isTemporary|
    //    +--------+----------+-----------+
    //    | default|test_table|      false|
    //    +--------+----------+-----------+

       println("Query a table in Hive:")
       spark.sql("SELECT * FROM default.test_table;").show()
    
    // Error:
    // Call From My-PC/123.456.78.9 to namenode:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information;
  }
}

Here is the output of the connectivity test done inside the spark-worker:
# ping namenode
PING namenode (172.18.0.9): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.9: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.280 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.9: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.161 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.9: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.138 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.9: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.195 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.9: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.192 ms
--- namenode ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.138/0.193/0.280 ms
# nc -zv namenode 9000
namenode (172.18.0.9:9000) open
# ping hive-metastore
PING hive-metastore (172.18.0.6): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.6: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.193 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.6: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.161 ms
--- hive-metastore ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.161/0.177/0.193 ms
# nc -zv hive-metastore 9083
hive-metastore (172.18.0.6:9083) open
# netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:42043        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.18.0.12:36585 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:57887        0.0.0.0:*

Update:
I added e 9000:9000 instead of 9010:9000, then added hostname namenode with ip 127.0.0.1 to the windows hosts file:
127.0.0.1 namenode

Now, when I run the code, it doesn't throw an error but continues to run indefinitely:
24/09/14 23:31:14 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20240914213107-0002/2 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
24/09/14 23:31:14 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20240914213107-0002/2 removed: Command exited with code 1
24/09/14 23:31:14 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20240914213107-0002/3 on worker-20240914210300-123.45.6.75-43893 (123.45.6.75:43893) with 8 core(s)
24/09/14 23:31:14 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 2 requested
24/09/14 23:31:14 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 2
24/09/14 23:31:14 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20240914213107-0002/3 on hostPort 123.45.6.75:43893 with 8 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
24/09/14 23:31:14 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 2 from BlockManagerMaster.
24/09/14 23:31:14 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20240914213107-0002/3 is now RUNNING
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 27.9508 ms
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 286.2 KiB, free 1983.0 MiB)
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 24.0 KiB, free 1983.0 MiB)
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on My-PC:55526 (size: 24.0 KiB, free: 1983.3 MiB)
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from 
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: show at HiveTest2.scala:38
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (show at HiveTest2.scala:38) with 1 output partitions
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (show at HiveTest2.scala:38)
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at show at HiveTest2.scala:38), which has no missing parents
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 12.7 KiB, free 1983.0 MiB)
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 6.2 KiB, free 1983.0 MiB)
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on My-PC:55526 (size: 6.2 KiB, free: 1983.3 MiB)
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1200
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at show at HiveTest2.scala:38) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
24/09/14 23:31:15 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
24/09/14 23:31:17 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20240914213107-0002/3 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
24/09/14 23:31:17 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20240914213107-0002/3 removed: Command exited with code 1
24/09/14 23:31:17 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 3 requested
24/09/14 23:31:17 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 3 from BlockManagerMaster.
24/09/14 23:31:17 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 3
24/09/14 23:31:17 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20240914213107-0002/4 on worker-20240914210300-123.45.6.75-43893 (123.45.6.75:43893) with 8 core(s)
24/09/14 23:31:17 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20240914213107-0002/4 on hostPort 123.45.6.75:43893 with 8 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
24/09/14 23:31:17 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20240914213107-0002/4 is now RUNNING
24/09/14 23:31:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20240914213107-0002/4 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
24/09/14 23:31:19 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20240914213107-0002/4 removed: Command exited with code 1
24/09/14 23:31:19 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 4 from BlockManagerMaster.
24/09/14 23:31:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 4 requested

and the error repeats with the executor index increasing.

there is literally nothing in the compose.yaml file that publishes 9100.

comment as I am not familiar with Hadoop, but a common pattern in this type of cluster is to allow clients to connect to any member, but redirect them to the correct/active member for their request. This means you can't do port redirection in docker: 9010:9000 as you get redirected to a port docker isn't listening on

9100 was a typo. I mean 9010

This mapping (9010:9000) allows Spark to connect to the Namenode via port 9010, which Docker will redirect to port 9000 inside the container. As you see in the comments between the code, 9010 is working for the first two queries

Any suggestion is welcome

it is exactly the same unsolved problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74874133/how-to-connect-to-hdfs-deployed-in-the-docker

"localhost:9010" is valid on the host to connect. "namenode:9000" is valid for container to container comms. "namenode:9010" is never valid as your host can't resolve dockers service mesh names, and 9010 is only published to the host. you are mixing network paradigms.

I understand what you are saying. The problem is what ever I write as spark session settings, the error remains the same.
I tried:
val spark = SparkSession.builder()       .appName("HiveMetastoreCheck")       .master("spark://spark-master:7077")       .master("local[*]")'       .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9010")       .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hive-metastore:9083")       .enableHiveSupport()       .getOrCreate()
Error:
Call From My-PC/123.456.78.9 to namenode:9000 failed on connection

Do you have any suggestion to fix the code?

First, don't set the master twice. As mentioned, you should never use localhost or port 9010. That's only valid outside of Docker, not where your Spark code is actually running. If Spark cannot resolve/connect to namenode:9000, then you should exec into the worker container and start running ping and netstat commands to check basic connectivity

the first master was commented. my bad....

Will you write me the correct SparkSession command to run?

I will test the ping and netstate as you mentioned

See the update of my question for the connectivity test and please let me know what other tests are necessary to run

@zori see my update inside the question.

I also added spark-master and hive-metastore to host but the result is the same.

Maybe you have incompatible images. You have 2.3.2 and also 2.3.0.

There should be a port in the postgres uri where postgres is running like jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore:5432/metastore

Now it seems like executors are starting and then failing with an error. Have you tried to increase memory (and cores if available)?
spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:3.0.0-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4g
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4 #it's optional, if available

UPD:
What I have done:

Cloned repo
run docker compose up command with your docker-compose.yml
started spark shell

   docker exec -it spark-master bash
   spark/bin/spark-shell --master spark://spark-master:7077


Run your spark code.

   scala> object HiveCheck {
        |   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        |     val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        |       .appName("HiveMetastoreCheck")
        |       .master("spark://spark-master:7077")
        |       .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://namenode:9010")
        |       .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hive-metastore:9083")
        |       .enableHiveSupport()
        |       .getOrCreate()
        | 
        |       println("Databases in Hive:")
        |       spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show()
        |
        | 
        |       println("Tables in database 'default':")
        |       spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN default").show()
        | 
        | 
        |        println("Query a table in Hive:")
        |        spark.sql("SELECT * FROM default.test_table;").show()
        |     
        |   }
        | }
   defined object HiveCheck


Created and filled the table

    scala> spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.test_table2 (id_studente INT, nome_corso STRING, voto INT, data_esame STRING)")
       24/09/19 10:11:09 WARN HiveMetaStore: Location: file:/spark-warehouse/test_table2 specified for non-external table:test_table2

   scala> spark.sql("INSERT INTO default.test_table2 VALUES (1, 'Corso2', 29, '2024-09-06')")
   res23: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []


I have no issues with querying a table

scala> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM default.test_table2;").show()
+-----------+----------+----+----------+
|id_studente|nome_corso|voto|data_esame|
+-----------+----------+----+----------+
+-----------+----------+----+----------+


Thanks. will take a look later.... Did you test it?

Actually yes.
I can see the table
scala>        spark.sql("SELECT * FROM default.test_table;").show()
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
+---+----+

Could you please specify how are you creating a table? In this case I can give you much more detailed answer

I see the table doesn't have any content. I want to see the content

I did like this but you can do anyhow you prefer:
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE if not exists default.test_table (id INT, name STRING);").show()
spark.sql("INSERT INTO default.test_table (id_studente, nome_corso, voto, data_esame) VALUES(1, 'Corso2', 29, '2024-09-06');")

I have updated my answer with detailed guide how I run it. Could you please check?

I run the scala comands outside of the container using Intelliji

So try to run them inside the container, it is the way, according to the documentation

The question is about running it outside the container.

I tried  the solution. it doesnt work

Read my comment for bounty: I want an answer that allow me to connect to the container and query a table.
It means outside the container
